# Selenium PageObject pattern: get objects list

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

I have an application page that provides some sort of search and it returns the list of search result items to the user.
So initally my test logs on to the application, and start search on the home page like this:

```
HomePage homePage = loginPage.login();     
homePage.searchFor(items);
```

What would be the best practiced way to test for search result contains the expected list items from the design side?

1. I could add method returning result items to the Page objects and then I can do anything I want with them on the test class.

   ```
   public void someTest(List<Items> expectedResultItems) {
       ...
       HomePage homePage = loginPage.login();     
       homePage.searchFor(items);  
       List<Item> resultItems = homePage.getItems();
       Util.compareItems(resultItems, expectedResultItems);
   }
   ```
2. I can add comparison method to the page object itself.

   ```
   public void someTest(List<Items> expectedResultItems) {   

       ...
       HomePage homePage = loginPage.login();     
       homePage.searchFor(items);  
       homePage.compareItems(List<Item expectedItems);
   }
   ```

Comment: The page object should not be making any assertions or checking of any kind. It should be responsible for **returning** the results that are displayed on the web page and the test should be responsible for comparing it. So the first one is better.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) and [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#chapter06-reference)

> There is a lot of flexibility in how the page objects may be designed,
>   but there are a few basic rules for getting the desired
>   maintainability of your test code. Page objects themselves should
>   never be make verifications or assertions. This is part of your test
>   and should always be within the test’s code, never in an page object.
>   The page object will contain the representation of the page, and the
>   services the page provides via methods but no code related to what is
>   being tested should be within the page object.

So based on this guideline go with the first one. Having the assertions in the test and not buried somewhere down in your page object makes your test easier to read and understand what it is doing.

That being said, i personally tend to use the second approach and this is mainly because i kind of started out like this and now i am just used to it. So i basically just have a public method in the pageObject similar to `public void validateSearchResults(List<?> expected) ...` and i make a separate call to it. By this i mean that I don't write chained methods like `getSearchDataAndValidate(List<?> expected)` which would also call the validate method. So i can use them seperately and i can reuse the search method without doing the actual validation if i need it in another test. You might question that why not validate your list everytime, but if your test suite grows bigger, it can backfire in terms of performance.